# Improve download speed of python script

Tags: python, python-requests, operating-system, urllib

I have a python script that downloads a file a server. When using chrome or internet download manager the file takes about 22 minutes to download, but when running the script it takes about 53 minutes. That is almost 2 times slower than using a browser. Thus, my question is what optimization can I do to improve the download speed. This is my script for reference.

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
import time
import urllib.request
import patoolib

# Create the URL and filename
url = 'http://perfectstormmod.com/update/PerfectStorm.7z'
file_name = 'PerfectStormTest.7z'

# Get the current directory
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# For timing the download
start_time = time.time()

# Start the download
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    print('File is downloading')
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

# Print to console when the download is done
print(f'File has finished downloading in {time.time() - start_time} seconds')

# Extract the downloaded file to the current folder.
patoolib.extract_archive('PerfectStormTest.7z', outdir=application_path)

input('\nPlease press enter to quit')
```

Comment: I've never used *copyfileobj*, but pydoc says it takes a 3rd optional parameter, the buffer size.  I/O performance is often affected by buffer size choices.  I'd try -1 and 64*1024 as options, and see if they make any difference.  On Linux, you can also use strace(1) to see how write is used in Python and the browser.

Comment: @James K. Lowden the strace(1) on linux sounds very interesting. I'm on windows though. Your comment about buffer size choices also makes sense, so I'll experiment with various sizes to see if they have an effect.